PAss a variable between jenkins stages
I am working in jenkins and I have a jenkins file. Here is a sample:
environment {
  var1 = "city1"
  var2 = "city2"
}
stages{
  stage('stage 1 - define a var and load a script') {
    steps {
      script {
        var = load jenkins/methods.groovy
        env.list = var.mymethod(var1)
      {
    }
  }
  stage('stage 2 - use defined stuff in stage1') {
    steps {
      script {
        var.mymethod2(env.list[1], env.list[0])
      {

    }
  }
}

In stage 1, I am loading my methods.groovy and using mymethod (from methods.groovy) to get a list (2 values) into env.list.
In stage 2 I want to use env.list values ([0],[1]) and load them into another method (mymethod2).
Not sure why but those values are not being passed from stage 1 to stage 2.
Can I get some help on this please?


it's unclear if your var is defined as a variable outside the pipeline block - if it isn't, it should be null within the second stage 2) AFAIR, Jenkins does not allow the environment variables to be anything but strings (which generally makes sense).


In cases like this, usually I define "global" variables.
So for example:
def myVar
def myList = []

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('stage 1') {
      steps {
        script {
          myVar = 'Hello'
          myList = myLib.myMethod
        }
      }
    }
    stage('stage 2') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo "myVar --> ${myvar}"
          echo "myList --> ${myList}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, neither the best way, but it works.

Outside pipeline? Or inside environment {}?

Outside pipeline
